# Pick elements of an array using cuda

Tags: cuda

I'd like to pick triangles from an array meeting a certain criteria. 
How would I do something like that in CUDA?

The input is an array of triangles. CUDA then calculates a value for each triangle.
The output should be an array consisting of those triangles where value is less than a threshold, 2 for example.

```
triangle array:     [tri1][tri2][tri3][tri4]
value array:        [1.00][0.50][3.50][0.50]
-> pick triangles with value <= 2
output:             [tri1][tri2][tri4]
```

I'm not sure how to optimaly exploit cudas parallelism in this case.

At the moment I read the value array back into mathematica and use Cases[] to select the triangles which is way too slow.

```
result = CUDAMemoryGet[cOutput];
validTriangleIndices = Cases[Range[Length[result]], x_ /; result[[x]] < threshold];
```

Comment: What is a "triangle" in your usage case? Is it a structure, or a vector type, of what. Details matter and I don't thing you have described your problem thoroughly enough to make this an answerable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @talonmies says, you haven't really provided enough information in your question for a complete answer. However, what you are describing sounds like a good fit for [Thrust](http://thrust.github.io)'s [copy_if](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html) algorithm. Check out [this example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/stream_compaction.cu).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the copy_if method. This led me further to the atomicAdd() function which I can use to get an index for the new array where I can store valid triangles.